# how draw canny result over image?

Tags: c++, opencv

i want to draw the canni result on the original image. How can i do this? i tried like this, but an error comes out

```
Mat image;
image = imread("C:\\test.jpg",1);


Mat gray, edqes, out;
cvtColor(image, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Canny(gray, edqes, 100, 200, 3);
out.copyTo(image,edqes);


cvNamedWindow("original",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("binary",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("canny",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvNamedWindow("out",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

imshow("original",image);
imshow("binary", gray);
imshow("canny", edqes);
imshow("out", out);


cvWaitKey(0);


cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

Comment: what error is that?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cvtColor(edqes, edqes, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
bitwise_or(edqes,image,out);
```